# Calligraphic style Math Font for letter Q

Tags: math-mode, fonts, symbols, amsmath

I am working on a mathematical document in LaTeX, and I would like to use a unique calligraphic-style font for the letter 'Q'. However, the standard calligraphic math fonts do not exactly match the style I have in mind. I want the letter Q to match the picture below:
[image: Q-learning Formula]

The code is as below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{equation}
    \delta_t = r_t + \gamma Q(s_{t+1},a_{t+1})-Q(s_t,a_t)
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

I have explored various options like using the \mathcal{} command for calligraphic fonts, but none produce the desired result for the letter 'Q'. I am not interested in using external image-based solutions, as I want the letter to remain fully scalable within the LaTeX document.
Any help is truly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  But I am sorry to report that the Q you are looking for is *not* calligraphic, but one of the many variations on a standard roman Q.  And indeed, it has been identified as such.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thank you for your input, and I appreciate your observation.

Comment: To be more specific, that particular _Q_ – just like the _r_, _a_, _s_ and _t_ (but not the _δ_ or _γ_) – is quite simply the standard uppercase Q in your variant of Times Italic or Times New Roman Italic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` packages to obtain the similar image below.

[image]

```
%% Compile and read me!
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{equation}
    \delta_t = r_t + \gamma Q(s_{t+1},a_{t+1})-Q(s_t,a_t)
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

If you use `mathptmx` package you can obtain the same picture desidered.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{equation}
    \delta_t = r_t + \gamma Q(s_{t+1},a_{t+1})-Q(s_t,a_t)
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your assistance and wisdom. My gratitude to you.

Comment: @WindstrideR Oh but I have not done nothing. :-)